# Handle mongodb connection issues on startup

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, startup, autowired

I've integrated MongoDB using Spring, my data service has a mongo repository autowired, and it all works.  Except when the db is down during startup.

When mongo is down while the service comes up, there's an exception thrown during initialization,  and in that case the whole service fails to start up.  This is not what I want obviously.

What I would like to happen is to catch the exception and start the service, and handle the db availability problem gracefully (like show a page saying we've got temporary problems, use a cache, or whatever)

My repository class:

```
public interface MediaDataRepository extends MongoRepository<MediaData, String> {
...
}
```

My service class:

```
@Service
public class MediaDataService {
    @Autowired
    private MediaDataRepository mediaDataRepository;
...
}
```

And Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/consumer")
public class MediaController extends HtmlGenerationController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MediaController.class);

    @Autowired
    private MediaDataService mediaDataService;
...
}
```

The error I get during startup:

```
2013-01-15 17:50:09.163:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/code/src/main/webapp/},file:/code/src/main/webapp/
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.service.MediaDataService com.myservice.controller.MediaController.mediaDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.repository.MediaDataRepository com.myservice.service.MediaDataService.mediaDataRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.service.MediaDataService com.myservice.controller.MediaController.mediaDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.repository.MediaDataRepository com.myservice.service.MediaDataService.mediaDataRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
[CLIPPED TO ALLOW QUESTION SIZE]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.repository.MediaDataRepository com.myservice.service.MediaDataService.mediaDataRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
[CLIPPED TO ALLOW QUESTION SIZE]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myservice.repository.MediaDataRepository com.myservice.service.MediaDataService.mediaDataRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
[CLIPPED TO ALLOW QUESTION SIZE]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaDataRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
[CLIPPED TO ALLOW QUESTION SIZE]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/myservice_db
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:626)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.createIndex(DBApiLayer.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:436)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:515)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.ensureIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:130)
[CLIPPED TO ALLOW QUESTION SIZE]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:626)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.createIndex(DBApiLayer.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:436)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:515)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.ensureIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:364)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.DefaultEntityInformationCreator.getEntityInformation(DefaultEntityInformationCreator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.DefaultEntityInformationCreator.getEntityInformation(DefaultEntityInformationCreator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:131)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:38)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Comment: i did't understood your question. could you explain more clearly?

Comment: yup.  I've integrated mongodb successfully, and it works great.  However, I have a problem when I try to start my service while mongodb is unavailable.  The problem is that because of autowiring, Spring tries to initialize my mongodb repository object, and fails because it tries to communicate with mongo.  When that happens, it stops my whole service from starting up, so instead of being able to show some kind of an error message or even use a cached version of my data, any request gets a 503 service unavailable response.

Comment: As you can see in the exception, this happens in the org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) phase, which means (I'm assuming) that my web application does not finish the init phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my searches, I found no good way to make Spring handle this directly. You likely need to put a proxy between your service and the repository. A post here: [How to make App server to start even if database is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244618/how-to-make-app-server-to-start-even-if-database-is-down) approaches this issue.

For you, this probably means having a bean (RepositoryProxy) which Spring creates. This bean will try to create the Mongo connection manually, or get the repository from the application context's lazy bean. If the Mongo connection fails, it catches the exception and creates a connection/object for cached data or error responses. It may also create a timer process to reconnect to the Mongo instance.

Comment: I have different repository classes for different objects, so this would make everything much more complicated.  If nobody comes up with a bright idea I'll award the points for lack of a better answer, but still waiting for a hero...

Comment: Agreed; It's not perfect (I cringe at it) but I haven't found anything better.

Comment: This is indeed the pattern I've used many times in the past for this sort of problem. Actually, it's not a Spring-specific pattern - it's just "connection management": proxying access to a resource connection through a manager that knows how to handle connection failure, perhaps failover to a standby service, smart background re-connection, etc.

Comment: I've implemented a JDBC DataSource ConnectionManager before using Spring XML config, but not yet via annotations (it might/might not be easy to implement). Can you not create a ManagedRepository (say) that implements MongoRepository and acts as fault-tolerant proxy to an embedded concrete repository, e.g. MediaDataRepository?